# Unable to post question despite having no hyperlinks

Tags: support, hyperlinks, asking-questions, new-users

I've removed all hyperlinks but SO will not let me post a question! It says:

> We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink. Earn 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your actual question is the combination of the posts you've been making here, you cause a break point at the 3rd section because it contains the following string:

> http://www.cspan.org/RECENT.html

You already have that string in the first section, and neither is formatted in a fashion that will exclude it as a link. So as far as Stack Overflow is concerned, you're posting hyperlinks. If you format the post so that they are in something of a code block, then it will not be blocked. You can do this by inserting 4 spaces in front, or clicking the 101010 button on the text editor UI.

Here's how the full post might look (or, at least, the first 3 posts worth of material). You can even copy it directly from [the source of my post body](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/805f0ea7-7f6b-457f-9c30-1ee6e90370e7/view-source). I tested this while logged out at SU, I would receive the spam prevention error if I didn't include code formatting, but did not receive the error afterwards.

---

I'm trying to do a simple tutorial but I'm having trouble getting started. My problem seems to be installing and getting the correct path to the modules.

******1. Here is the original code:***********

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP 5.64;

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'http://www.cspan.org/RECENT.html';
my $response = $browser->get($url);

die "Can't get $url -- ", $response->status_line
    unless $response->is_success;

my $html = $response->content;
while( $html =~m/<A HREF=\"(.*?)\"/g ) {
    print "$1\n";
```

******2. But in Host Gator they say this:******

Location of Your Perl Module(s)

Path: /home/dgertgen/perl

Using Your Perl Module(s)

You will need to add /home/dgertgen/perl to the include path.
You can do this by adding the following code to your script:

```
BEGIN {
    my $base_module_dir = (-d '/home/dgertgen/perl' ? '/home/dgertgen/perl' : ( getpwuid($>) )[7] . '/perl/');
    unshift @INC, map { $base_module_dir . $_ } @INC;
}
```

******3. So I added the code but have no idea if I added it in the correct spot.******

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP 5.64;

BEGIN {
    my $base_module_dir = (-d '/home/dgertgen/perl' ?

'/home/dgertgen/perl' : ( getpwuid($>) )[7] . '/perl/');
    unshift @INC, map { $base_module_dir . $_ } @INC;
}


my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'http://www.cspan.org/RECENT.html';
my $response = $browser->get($url);

die "Can't get $url -- ", $response->status_line
    unless $response->is_success;

my $html = $response->content;
while( $html =~m/<A HREF=\"(.*?)\"/g ) {
    print "$1\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As Craig points out, you *were* able to post a question - this one, as it was [migrated from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019481/unable-to-post-question-despite-having-no-hyperlinks-closed).  It's possible that some part of your question was (rightly or wrongly) interpreted to contain hyperlinks.  Try pasting your question content here.  If MSO interprets some part of your question as hyperlinks *again*, cut the text down piece by piece until you're able to post, and that'll give you and us a hint.