# Don't refuse my post because of more than one hyperlink-looking item

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, new-users, rate-limiting

Here are my feature requests for the forum:

1) Learn how to count what are in fact explicit links (the other things apparently counting as links in my post aren't--they're output.

2) Get past demonstrating superiority over noobs: post a comment next to my name saying "Idiot newcomer" if you like, but don't suppress my posts just because I don't have enough stripes on my sleeve or ribbons on my chest.

Other forums don't subject their citizens to some of these silly rules.

Comment: These "silly rules" are what makes SO so massively useful.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is the place for this.

Comment: It's because this is not a forum

Answer (score 7):

Regarding point 1, if you use proper code formatting by indenting your samples with four spaces or with backticks, then [as demonstrated here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53260/unable-to-post-question-despite-having-no-hyperlinks/53342#53342) you will avoid the hyperlink block when it comes to things that aren't actually links. That is how you can tell the system that your links aren't links but are output.

The suppression measure has a very low reputation barrier, it's not meant to limit people for very long. It's primarily a measure against spam.

Answer (score 1):

1) Spammers would surely like that :-) Not that they would live long here but it would be a lot of hazzle.

2) That is already obvious by the number next to your name which is your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I went back over your question/answer history and nobody "[demonstrated] superiority over noobs".  Sensitive, much?

Comment: When someone is already frustrated, (validly or not) I don't think it's appropriate to mock or make fun of them. Especially for a moderator.